# len() in Python's duplicated set items

Tags: python, set

I have a python snippet for a set (**we know that set is not for duplicate items**), however, should it still not display the number of items as perceived below?

```
set2={1,2,3,'a','b','c',True,False,False}
print('Set:',set2, "Length:",len(set2))
```

**My assumption:**
The above code to return the length to be '8' as there are two 'False' items.

But this is the output:
`Set: {False, 1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'} Length: 7`

Comment: A set only stores 1 of each thing. You add 2 False and it will only keep 1. Each value in a set is unique.

Comment: True and 1 are also duplicates

Comment: A set can only contain unique items.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `collections.Counter` instead. This acts much like a set, however, it will keep track of the number of occurrences of each item registered.